# Web Server Accessible From Outside LAN But Not From Within LAN

Tags: networking, apache2, dns, lan

Web server works as expected from outside the LAN, enter the URL into a browser or application and the correct page is returned. Within the same LAN from another computer or device an "unable to connect" message is presented.

Entering the local web server IP address from within the LAN works but none of the URL based links within the page work. Appears the URL is not resolved within the LAN.

Results from several web searches suggest adding a private DNS to the LAN. Is this the best approach so all computers and devices (IOS, Android) inside the LAN work the same as computers and devices outside the LAN? Are there alternatives?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `dig web_server_name`? Also can you connect to your webserver if you enter the IP address that an external client would resolve the URL to? My guess is that your router is blocking any requests from your LAN to access a machine on the LAN using an external IP address. I use dnsmasq (on Ubuntu server) to resolve the names of hosts on my LAN to the LAN IP address rather than the WAN address. This works well with Linux, windows, but not OSX for some reason.

Comment: Results from dig (99.999.999.999 resolves to the correct external IP):  

`; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> www.hostname.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24132
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.hostname.net.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.hostname.net. 234 IN A 99.999.999.999

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu May 04 14:07:38 EDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55`

Cannot connect  using the external IP from within the LAN.

Comment: It looks to me like your router or firewall is blocking a request made on the LAN to the external IP address of the LAN. I think that your options are either to reconfigure your router/firewall (if you can do this safely) or you can set up a local DNS server that will resolve the URL to the IP address on the LAN. This is what I do -- I followed [Dan Bishops guide](https://www.danbishop.org/2012/06/02/ubuntu-12-04-ultimate-server-guide/#part-1-dhcp-and-dns) which was written for Ubuntu 12.04 but I run 16.04 and it works fine. (As a word of warning, this method doesnt seem to work with OSX)

Comment: The router is an Apple Extreme behind a Ubiquiti router/antenna (internet is provided over the air at this location) and I am not sure which might be blocking any requests.  Will take your advice and setup a local DNS server either on a Linux server or the extra Raspberry PI.  This seems to be the better alternative.  Thank you for the guidance.